# Binding redirect not working correctly

Tags: binding, dapper

```
<runtime>
<dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Dapper.SqlMapper" publicKeyToken="032d34d3e998f237"  culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.38.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

I am trying to learn dapper and I am having to use a binding redirect but am having trouble getting it to work. This is what I have so far.
I am getting this error,
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Dapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load type 'Dapper.SqlMapper' from assembly 'Dapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

```
publicKeyToken="032d34d3e998f237"
```

vs

```
PublicKeyToken=null
```

You can't redirect a non-strong-named assembly to a strong-named one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately that didn't work any more suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @DrewWard I didn't say it would work; I pointed out why this **cannot** work; you **cannot** redirect a non-strong-named assembly to a strong-named one (nor can you change the strong-name via a redirect)

Answer (score 0):

> Additional information: Could not load type 'Dapper.SqlMapper' from
>   assembly 'Dapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

I was getting this exact error and couldn't get past it.  Then I got rid of the nuget package and instead copied the [SqlMapper.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs) into my project and the problem went away.